# Conversion Tracking for purchase behaviour + segmentation

Tags: marketing-cloud, conversion, email-tracking

I need to set up Conversion Tracking so I can track purchases on my website and then segment in Marketing Cloud to exclude people who have purchased in the last 6 months from my Email + journey Builder sends. What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: have you looked into the collect code, and track conversion call? This will populate the igo_purchase DE you may be able to leverage for segmentation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this suffices your Business Requirement, but you could go about this like

1.Your Purchase data inside a DE(say Transaction DE)should be pulled inside Salesforce. This can either be done by pushing the purchase data nightly through FTP and import into data extension. Or you could use APIs on the website to insert the purchase record in your DE.

2. You can then make use of SQL Query or data filter activity to filter purchases in last 6 months and exclude them.

Considerations:
1. You must set retention policy on your transaction DE, as this DE will grow very large with time.
2. You must have purchase date column in order to filter the data later.

Comment: This will not link the conversions to email sends, as requested by Ash